# Chain wear tool

Tags: chain

BBB Cycling, ChainChecker Multi Tool for Chain with Bike Hook for Road and Mountain Bikes, Hand Tool, Measurement Repair Kit, BTL-125, Silver https://amzn.eu/d/gOMZdUp

Or

KMC Easy Chain Checker Tool, Silver, Universal https://amzn.eu/d/e5HF8Gm

The KMC one seems to have accurate measurements, however it shows that if it's <0.8 then you're supposed to replace it but aren't you're supposed to replace the chain when it hits 0.75?

Comment: [Neither](https://www.google.com/search?q=ruler&tbm=isch).  As mentioned in the answer.  A ruler will *always* work.

Answer (score 4):

Usually, on this site questions that ask for specific product recommendations are discouraged. However, here it's important to note that most chain wear tools measure the incorrect thing. They do a measurement that's partially based on chain pitch, partially on roller clearance and partially on roller diameter. This measurement tells almost nothing.

You need a chain wear tool that does both measurements on the same side. As far as I know, there are only three families of such tools:

- Shimano TL-CN40, TL-CN41, TL-CN42
- Park Tool CC-4 (don't buy any other tool from the CC series, only CC-4 is accurate)
- Pedro's Chain Checker Plus II

Of these, the Shimano ones have one threshold (probably 0.5%, not specified) whereas Park Tool and Pedro's have 0.5% and 0.75% specified thresholds. That shouldn't matter as you should be replacing your chain already at 0.5% so the 0.75% threshold most likely only tells if you already have destroyed your sprockets, which you will find out anyway after the chain change.

[Here's more information about the problem with most chain wear tools.](http://pardo.net/bike/pic/fail-004/000.html)

So, to answer your question: neither. Both are crap.

Comment: They both measure 0.5% wear.

Comment: @Sam this answer is trying to explain that whilst both chain checkers you linked may show 0.5% they are flawed in their measurement system.

Comment: @Juhist i believe the pedros branded chain checker also does a 'same side' measurement

Comment: I bought the Parktool CC-4, did I make the right decision? It is expensive.

Comment: Buying Park Tool CC-4 is not a mistake, but using its 0.75% limit may be. However, it has a 0.5% limit too which causes less sprocket wear than 0.75%.